# Using different ram PCI-e configs than listed on CPU's website

Tags: cpu, pci-express

Will it work if I use different PCI-e RAM configuration than a CPU's website lists? I want to use 1x4GB + 1x8GB with the CPU i3-2328M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/70927/intel-core-i3-2328m-processor-3m-cache-2-20-ghz.html) sets the limit on the maximum amount of RAM (16 GB), as well as the supported speeds (DDR3 1066/1333).

Your *motherboard* and its memory controller determines the acceptable configurations and may impose more limits than the CPU.

You need to consult your computer and/or motherboard's manual to know what is compatible.

That being said, typically you can mix memory sizes and *sometimes* speeds.

Lastly, PCIe has nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: Thank you for help!